# Creating SQL indexes on old tables

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, workbench

I have a query that shows all workers with their first shift in the last week, it's gathered from two tables and looks like this:

```
SELECT MIN(p.start_date),
       CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) AS 'c.fullname',
       c.temp_nr
FROM contactstable c
LEFT JOIN projectlines p on c.temp_nr = p.candidate_number
WHERE c.contact_type = 'Candidate'
GROUP BY c.temp_nr
HAVING
    MIN(p.start_date)
        between
            DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (dayofweek(CURDATE())+6) DAY)
            AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE() , INTERVAL (dayofweek(CURDATE())) DAY)
```

My problem is the query times out, so as I understand it I need to add indexes, but after having searched around on multiple sites, I still have no clue how to go about that.

I am using Workbench 8.0

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you write the query like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) AS fullname, c.temp_nr,
       (SELECT MIN(p.start_date)
        FROM projectlines p 
        WHERE c.temp_nr = p.candidate_number
       ) as min_start_date
FROM contactstable c
WHERE c.contact_type = 'Candidate'
HAVING min_start_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (dayofweek(CURDATE())+6) DAY) AND
                              DATE_SUB(CURDATE() , INTERVAL (dayofweek(CURDATE())) DAY);
```

Then for this, you want indexes on:

- `contactstable(contact_type, temp_nr, first_name, last_name)`
- `projectlines(candidate_number, start_date)`.

Comment: Thanks! should the index query be posted before or after the SQL query? And if I do it once, will I have to do it again?
Am I correct in that it would look like this:
CREATE INDEX tempnr ON contactstable(contact_type, temp_nr, first_name, last_name)

Comment: @Frederik . . . The indexes should be created before you run the query.  Yes, you have the correct syntax for creating an index.